# How to create subdomain for each language?

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I want to make website in multiple languages, I do it right with cookies to detect the user preferred language.

Now I want to make each language has its sub-domain to be indexed in search engines, some thing like Facebook.

so I want to configure my Apache to point all my virtual hosts to the same folder, then use $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] to figure out what sub-domain was requested.

I start to use this code in my htaccess file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias en.mydomain.com ar.mydomain.com es.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but it doesn't work and I get cannot find server when I request es.mydomain.come so any help ?

BTW I use mod_rewrite after that code above! and I didn't create any sub-domain in cPanel!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can direct all subdomains to the same folder using a wildcard *

```
<VirtualHost *>
      ServerName mydomain.come
      ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the error message "can not find server" is most likely a DNS issue. If you are on Windows type "nslookup" on the command line, and type the problem domain name. If you get a non-authoritative answer with a valid IP address then it's working, but if you get "non-existent domain" then it's a DNS issue. Be advised, that DNS changes take 24+ hours to affect.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your CNAME records are fine as BluesRock said

try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /www/public //whatever the root is!
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias en.domain.com, es.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Another note to remember:

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]//will always show domain.com
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]//Will show en.domain.com if that is where they entered from.
```